# Is closing statement is good enough or must we also close each of the resultset?

Tags: java, jdbc

We have a java application which we use more then one statement variable. The problem why need more then one statement is that at time while runnning a loop for one result inside the loop we need some other query operation to be done. Most of the places the single stmt is used many times and finally we close. What we would like to confirm now is that we are not closing the resultset variables and we notice the usage of memory fluctuates.So what is the best mechanism to close the resultset immediately after we got the results or towards the end just before stmt is being closed?

Comment: At my last job we discovered that a ResultSet doesn't reach the end of the query (like if you don't loop while (rs.next())) and you don't close it, it can leak resources, at least with Oracle.  It didn't seem to leak if you ran it to the end of the query.

Comment: I would recommend you close the ResultSet as soon as you are done with it, same with Statement, same with Connection

Comment: I recommend `resultSet.getStatement().close();` Which closes both the statement and the ResultSet.

Comment: we cant close the statement as we keep reusing it many time else we have to set the connection to each new statement right? So immediately done with the resultset we will close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the JDBC Specification and the [`Statement.close()` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) it should be sufficient:

> Note:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

Based on that you should be able to assume that you only need to close a statement. However as a Statement can have a longer lifetime than the use of a single ResultSet obtained from it, it is a good idea in general to close the ResultSet as soon as possible.

A Statement can have a longer lifetime because for example you use it again to execute another query, or in case of a PreparedStatement to execute the query again with different parameters. In the case you execute another query, the previously obtained ResultSet will be closed.

Comment: is it the right way to keep reusing the statement or use each time a new one. I think reusing it is the practical way to move right and to be on the safe side just close the resultsets.

Comment: In general you should be using `PreparedStatement` together with parametrized queries as that protects you against SQL Injection, in the case you can only reuse a Statement for the same query (with different parameters). Other than that there is no real pro- or contra in reusing Statement or creating a new Statement.

Comment: I think we will take some time to move to preparedstatement as we have a lot of queries for now. So if we move to preparedstatement then for each query we must use a new Statement is it?

Comment: Yes, if the query text is different.

Comment: @user837306 and you should use separate statements for different SQL. Helps keeping the code clean and allows easier refactoring. Also the overhead of creating a new statement compared to executing it is tiny.

Comment: @stefan what you are saying is that for each query I create a new Statement just before the query and close it immediately after that but in my case I would need a lot of it? Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: @mark in the event there is memory leak where to look for indication of it in linux environment will there be any log file kept for this purpose? What will happen is that programme will crash right?

Comment: @user837306 Yes exactly. I think its good practice to keep methods and scopes as small as possible and using a new Statement every time helps with both.

Comment: @stefan so I will have many of this stmt = dbconn.createStatement(); each time I will create one before a new query would there be any extra overhead if I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Close it when you are finished with it, same as any other resource. Mo point in holding on to it for longer, especially if you are down to measuring memory, which implies a memory concern.

Comment: we do not close the stmt variable as we keep reusing through out the programme and close it only in the final statement that is fine right? So we will then close the resultset immediately after done with the reading and not in the final statement will that be ok?

Comment: @user837306 What part of 'when you are finished with it' isn't clear?

Comment: I am not clear when you said finished with close meaning for each query you are suggesting one new statement is it?

Comment: @user837306 I didn't say 'finished with close' at all, so I have no idea what you are now talking about.